# What do I read before diving into 2016 Spider-Man/Deadpool crossover comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, suggested-order, spider-man, deadpool

I've wanted to get into the comics side of things so I decided to start with the two characters I know best out of all of them, but I don't know what I should read beforehand. Should I read all of the comics or just selected ones?

I am talking about the [2016 crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man/Deadpool). I suppose I'm looking for things that might be brought up in that comic, if that makes sense.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It would help if you clarified which Spider-man/Deadpool crossover you're talking about.  The most obvious one is the [2016 series](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/19679/spider-mandeadpool_2016_-_2019), but there were others.  *Then* you need to explain what kind of, and how much, backstory you're looking for.

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. Bob thinks you should read every Deadpool and Spider-Man comic since Amazing Fantasy #15 and New Mutants #98. Robert, on the other hand thinks that you can start it without having read any of it.

Comment: @BennyBettsy - Have you read any Spider-Man or Deadpool comics from around that time period?

Comment: The first issue references a whole bunch of stuff from Uncanny Avengers (Vol. 3) and Avengers Vol. 6, Avengers Spider-man quitting, Wade's wife and stuff from much earlier like Dormammu (Doctor Strange Vol 4), the Mindless ones (Cable & Deadpool Vol 1), etc, etc. If you want to pull the thread on every reference you're going to need to go an awfully long way back.

Comment: @Valorum suggested order questions are by their nature opinion based.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - And while that's true, 'what do I read before x' questions are *highly* opinion-based.

Comment: @Valorum we’ve had many of those, including some very well received ones in the MCU about Endgame or IW, can’t remember which.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 0):

I've read a lot of Spider-Man comics, but not that many Deadpool comics. I started this particular series with [Spider-Man/Deadpool, Vol. 0: Don't Call it a Team-Up](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/27415880-spider-man-deadpool-vol-0). It doesn't relate to the plot of the series, though. It's really just a collection of team-ups between the two characters over the years. After that I read [Spider-Man/Deadpool Vol. 1: Isn't it Bromantic](https://www.marvel.com/comics/collection/52558/spider-mandeadpool_vol_1_isnt_it_bromantic_trade_paperback). I will just say that the book was less light-hearted than I'm used to from Spidey. I have not yet read any farther in the series.

Answer (score 0):

The comic has it's own story and is not related to any previous Spider/Deadpool issues. However, if you are not familiar with both superheroes I'd recommend reading their own sole issues first. For example you can do [The Amazing Spider-Man (2014 - 2015)](https://www.comicsmode.com/comics/the-amazing-spider-man-2015-chapters) and [Deadpool (2015 - 2017)](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/20613/deadpool_2015_-_2017). Both of these are amazing comics and you will definitely have a fun time.